# Adobe air for android,question about the phone call

Tags: android, air

How to access the phone call history,
and is it possible to do some action before I answer the phone call.
What I am trying to do is when I got a phone call,
before I answer it, I wanna it to check the my contacts saved in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for accessing phone call history

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);

String num= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// for  number
String name= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// for name
String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration
int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going
```

And as per my knowledge you cannot do any actions or you cannot guess that your call is picked up or not because android provides only 3 call states

1. Idle (normal state when you phone
   is sitting idle no call dialed or
   received)
2. offhook (when call is in
   dialing state or picked)
3. Ringing    (When there is an
   incoming call is    received picked
   up)

So there is no way to to know that the call is picked up or ringing or in dialing state or in hold state

Thankyou